# Invoke Google Chrome Navigation from outside chrome, i.e. CMD or C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

**Looking for a solution to invoke Navigation in Chrome from outside of chrome by external process.**

We have legacy WinForm Software that needs to browse an Angular HTML5 app that requires Chrome to run.  (I have no control of this.)

Something along lines of:

```
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = 
      @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "google.com" + " --new-window";
    process.Start();
```

And then some way to hook into that process and have the SAME TAB perform navigation.

```
magic.navigateTab1(www.anothersite.com);
```

I quite assume its not easily possible, solution may not use Process etc..  Just, anyway to accomplish it from outside chrome?

Whatever solution can't require installing > ~5MB to C# code base..  Ideally, no installation is preferred.

- http://cefsharp.github.io/ <- looked into this but this is huge.

Edit 1:  Perhaps using something like this..
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: You need to open chrome then go to a URL and you don't wanna use Process class, is this correct?

Comment: No I need a button to a login link, and site a link, etc..  and after chrome is open, clicking the button in another c# program causes chromes original open tab to navigate. i.e.  Multiple button presses, cause multiple navigations in same tab.

Comment: We dont want to spawn a new tab for each external navigation command.

Comment: So you need all the requests to go on the same tab

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  See update.

Comment: Have you taken a look at selenium. I know it's intended for automation testing of web apps but should do what you require.

Comment: Something with Selenium will/might work..  Hoping someone has solved it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium to achieve that.

First you must add via Nugget the following packages to your solution

```
Selenium.WebDriver
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver;
```

Then reference the following namespaces

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
```

Create the following property on your class root

```
IWebDriver driver;
```

On your class constructor add the following code to create a new Chrome Window handled by Selenium

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Then on your buttons add the following

```
// Switch the action target to the first tab opened on chrome instace handled by Selenium
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
// Go to a given URL
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yourURL.com.br");
```

Your code should be like that

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace configure
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yourURL.com.br");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: I tried this in a blank Winform application.  The moment I add the nuget package Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver, running the app produces a console, instead of my winform.  I have never experienced this before, but its readily duplicable..  Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver seems to be for Unit Test Projects..  Can you get this solution to run in a winform project?

Comment: Actually, it will open a separated console to Selenium, but your winforms application will still run, I've made a test using one... Yes, selenium purpose is Unit Testing... I know, it's not the ideial solution, but unfortunately I could not find another way out

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on `Program.Main() -> Application.Run(new Form1());` and its never hit..  The Form1 that used to show doesnt when console does, instead of in addition to.  Unfortunately that wont work for existing program.

Comment: It's weird, for me its working smoothly... I've added a sample code to the answer, checkout if it works on your machine, please

Comment: In blank WinForm Project, this code opens the exact code you have in your form1.   Merely installing the `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` causes all of the following code to never be called. `using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChromeDriver
{
   static class Program
   {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
   }
}`

Comment: So in a clean solution it runs well but on your current project it fails?

Comment: No, in a clean solution it doesn't run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156305/discussion-between-andre-santarosa-and-ttugates).